# How to make a horizontal top menu with submenues in a left side menu in Umbraco

Tags: c#, umbraco

I want to have the 1. level menu horizontal in top of my page, and sub and subsub menues vertikal in the left side.

I got the top menu ok, but the left side menu does not do what I want it to. If I click on a menu in the top then the left side is ok, but if I click on a menu in the left side, then the sub menues disappear and only the subsub menues shows

Top menu:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id="topmenu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            @foreach (var menuItem in Umbraco.TypedContentAtRoot().Where(e => e.IsVisible()).OrderBy(e => e.SortOrder))
            {
                //Check if menu item has children
                if (menuItem.Children.Any(m => m.IsVisible() && m.GetPropertyValue("naviShow").Equals(true)))
            {
                    <li class="dropdown @(menuItem.IsAncestorOrSelf(currentPage) ? "active" : "")">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target-menu="#@(menuItem.Id)">@menuItem.Name</a>
                    </li>
                }
                else
                {
                    <li class="@(menuItem.IsAncestorOrSelf(currentPage) ? "active" : "")">
                        <a href="@menuItem.Url">@menuItem.Name</a>
                    </li>
                }
            }
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Left menu:

```
@{ var selection = CurrentPage.Parent.Children.Where("Visible"); }

@if (selection.Any())
{
    <div class="submenu-container">
        @foreach (var item in selection)
        {
            <a class="submenu" href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>
            if (item.Children.Any())
            {
                foreach (var subpage in item.Children.Where("Visible"))
                {
                    <a class="subsubmenu" href="@subpage.Url">- @subpage.Name</a>
                }

            }
        }
    </div>
}
```

Also I want the subsub menues only to show when their parent or siblings are active

Answer (score 0):

I want to help but needs to understand your aim first, can you provide a link to a code playgrounds like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with a model of your html menu?

In case that isn't suitable for you just draw a mockup of the menu and post the image here.

**Important**: I need to know which *CSS framework* you have.

Comment: Hi @Abuabdellah this is more a problem of how to get the menu to render the correct items rather than how to use CSS/HTML - take a look at the tags on the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider what the context of the menu items in your side menu are.  Currently, you're looking for all pages under the *Parent* of the *Current* Page that are *Visible*:

```cs
var selection = CurrentPage.Parent.Children.Where("Visible")
```

When you click on a menu item in the side menu, the page will refresh showing that page, and the side menu also refreshes, showing *only the visible pages under the new pages parent*.

If you want that side menu to stay the same each time, you need to get your parent node at a consistent level.  Something like this perhaps:

```cs
var selection = CurrentPage.AncestorOrSelf(2).Children.Where("Visible");
```

`AncestorOrSelf(2)` will get the node that's the ancestor of the current page at level 2.  Level 1 is the top level root node iirc.

Comment: If I use var selection = CurrentPage.AncestorOrSelf(2).Children.Where("Visible") then there comes no side menu at all

Comment: Can you give an example of your content tree and which nodes you want shown?